# Where is mujoco_py.MjModel(<filepath>) defined?

Tags: python, c++, c, openai-gym

I have been studying some of the OpenAI gym envs and came across this line:

```
self.model = mujoco_py.MjModel(fullpath)
```

(https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/mujoco/mujoco_env.py#L28)

Can anyone tell me where mujoco_py.MjModel() is defined? I assume this is somehow pulled from native MuJoCo / Cython...

---

EDIT

Also when I search the install folder of mujoco_py (`<Python-installation-directory>/Lib/site-packages/mujoco_py/`), there is literally no `MjModel` found (Sublime fulltext search). (The search might exclude some files.) What I do find a lot are 'mjModel' and 'PyMjModel' though.

I am confused because the instantiation through mujoco_py.MjModel() also seems to create a different kind of model than using functions like mujoco_py.load_model_from_path(). The former have a `.data` attribute while the latter apparently don't.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `mujoco-py`, you can probably find `MjModel` in something like the following file:

`<Python-installation-directory>/Lib/site-packages/mujoco_py/mjcore.py`

You won't find that python file in the [mujoco-py repository](https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py) though. It probably gets generated from C++ code during the installation process (when running [setup.py](https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/blob/c5f60322467ec8ecc0db64c3e18a4da762c27e45/setup.py)). It looks like MjModel is defined in the [mjmodel.pxd](https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/blob/c5f60322467ec8ecc0db64c3e18a4da762c27e45/mujoco_py/pxd/mjmodel.pxd) file (for more info on .pxd files, see [this](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pxd_files.html)).